# mvc harvest chosen multiselect dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I followed Rick Anderson's example but I can't get it to work. I have the original multi select box but not the harvest chosen multiselect.

View:

```
@Html.ListBox("Clearances", ViewBag.Clearanceslist as MultiSelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", style="width:350px;" } })
```

under the view is my javascript:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
</script>
}
```

This is the scripts I included in the BundleConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"
                ));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
    // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",                      
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
              "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/datepicker.css",
              "~/Content/chosen.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
}
```

Controller:

```
private MultiSelectList GetClearances(string[] selectedValues)
{
    return new MultiSelectList(db.Clearances.Where(c => c.Active == true), "ClearanceID", "ClearanceName", selectedValues);
}

// GET: CardKeys/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Clearanceslist = GetClearances(null);
    return View();
}
```

What else do I miss?

Comment: Have you included the relevant scripts? What error messages are you getting in the browser console? (and a link to the 'example' your referring to might help to understand what your wanting to do)

Comment: I have included all relevant scripts (I believe). I didn't get any error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make 100% sure that the reference to the `chosen.jquery.js` script is made after the reference to the `jQuery` script otherwise your chosen plugin will not work properly.

If your layout is complex and made of many sections, I advise you to check it via browser developer tool or opening the source code of the page.

Also make sure that the jQuery script is not loaded multiple times.

---

Another thing that I would do is change the View code as follows:

```
@Html.ListBox("Clearances", ViewBag.Clearanceslist as MultiSelectList, new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", style="width:350px;" })
```

Have you checked in your version the HTML that is rendered?
Something like this:

```
<select htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control chosen-select, style = width:350px; }" id="Clearances" multiple="multiple" name="Clearances">
...
</select>
```

jQuery will not get the element correctly with this kind of HTML.

Comment: I edited my post and included my BundleConflig.cs file. You can see chosen.jquery.js file is under the jquery-{version}.js file

Answer (score 0):

You have added the file to the bundle correctly in your bundle config, but where are you actually calling that bundle?

Try changing it as follows

```
 @section Scripts {
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

 <script type="text/javascript">
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
</script>
}
```

Comment: This was called in the _Layout.cshtml view at the bottom:
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it has nothing to do with script including. But the html rendering on this line was problematic:

```
@Html.ListBox("Clearances", ViewBag.Clearanceslist as MultiSelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", style="width:350px;" } })
```

this line will render html like this, which will prevent chose from working correctly:

```
<select htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control chosen-select, style = width:350px; }" id="Clearances" multiple="multiple" name="Clearances">
```

After I changed it to:

```
@Html.ListBox("Clearances", ViewBag.Clearanceslist as MultiSelectList, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", style="width:350px;" } )
```

Now it works perfectly.

Comment: I had updated my answer to signal you about the Html helper problem. I'm glad you found out ;)